# thread creation with a member function runs before the object constructor finishes in for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, constructor

I'm coding a simple client/server multithread program. The client threads are created like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    clients.emplace_back(work_finished, updated[i], free_client_count,i);
    client_threads.emplace_back([&]
    {
        clients[i].work();
    });
}
```

And the initiation parameters are

```
std::atomic_bool work_finished;
    work_finished.store(false);
    std::atomic_bool updated[4];
    updated[0].store(false);
    updated[1].store(false);
    updated[2].store(false);
    updated[3].store(false);
    atomic_int free_client_count;
    free_client_count.store(0);
```

But these client threads wouldn't run as expected, always result in a invalid memory access during `update[i].load()`.  If I create another for loop to create the threads, there is no problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    clients.emplace_back(work_finished, updated[i], free_client_count,i);

}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    client_threads.emplace_back([&]
    {
        clients[i].work();
    });
}
```

Then I add some log information to client constructor. It turns out that sometimes the `client.work()` is called before the constructor finishes, which result in an invalid memory access of `update_recieved.load()` because the `update_recieved` is not initiated yet.

Here comes the question: why would `work` be called before the client is constructed when they are in the same loop? And why it's right to break the client constructor and thread constructor.
The complete code is below

```
    using namespace std;
class client
{
public:
    std::atomic_int& ready_thread_count;
    std::atomic_bool& update_recieved;
    std::atomic_bool& work_finished;
    const int i;
    void recieve()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!update_recieved.load())
            {
                //std::cout << "not recieved " << i << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
            std::cout << "recieved " << i << std::endl;
            update_recieved.store(false);
        }
        catch (std::exception e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }


    }
     void compute()
    {
        // do something
    }
    void send()
    {
        ready_thread_count++;
    }
public:
    client(std::atomic_bool& in_work_finished, std::atomic_bool& in_update_recieved, std::atomic_int& in_free_thread_count,int in_i)
        :work_finished(in_work_finished), update_recieved(in_update_recieved), ready_thread_count(in_free_thread_count), i(in_i)
    {
        std::cout << "client created " << i << std::endl;
    }
     void work()
    {
        recieve();
        while (!work_finished.load())
        {
            compute();
            send();
            recieve();
        }
        send();

    }
};
class server
{
public:
    std::atomic_int& ready_thread_count;
    std::atomic_bool* update_recieved_vector;
    std::atomic_bool& work_finished;
    const std::chrono::microseconds wait_time;
    const int client_number;
    int iteration;
    void send()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < client_number; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "update client " << i << std::endl;
            update_recieved_vector[i].store(true);
        }
    }
     void compute()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(wait_time);
        iteration++;
        std::cout << iteration << std::endl;
        if (iteration == 50)
        {
            work_finished.store(true);
        }
    }
     void recieve()
    {
        while (ready_thread_count.load() != client_number)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(wait_time);
        }
        ready_thread_count.store(0);
    }
public:
    server(std::atomic_int& in_free_thread_count, std::atomic_bool* in_update_recieved_vector, std::atomic_bool& in_work_finished, int in_client_member, int in_wait_time)
        :ready_thread_count(in_free_thread_count), update_recieved_vector(in_update_recieved_vector), work_finished(in_work_finished), client_number(in_client_member), wait_time(in_wait_time)
    {
        iteration = 0;
    }
     void work()
    {
        while (!work_finished.load())
        {
            send();
            recieve();
            compute();
        }
        send();
        recieve();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::atomic_bool work_finished;
    work_finished.store(false);
    std::atomic_bool updated[4];
    updated[0].store(false);
    updated[1].store(false);
    updated[2].store(false);
    updated[3].store(false);
    atomic_int free_client_count;
    free_client_count.store(0);
    server local_server(free_client_count, updated, work_finished, 4, 20);
    vector<client> clients;
    vector<thread> client_threads;
    thread server_thread(&server::work, &local_server);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        clients.emplace_back(work_finished, updated[i], free_client_count,i);
        client_threads.emplace_back([&]
        {
            clients[i].work();
        });
    }

    server_thread.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        client_threads[i].join();
    }
    std::cout << "finaly" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should reduce your code to a minimal example before posting here, there's a lot that is probably not necessary. Anyhow, the lambda you pass to the thread's constructor has a reference to the loop variable `i`. If that lambda is executed after the subsequent increment of the loop variable, it will see the new value. BTW: Using `std::vector`, you need to handle the case that it gets reallocated while adding elements, so you need to synchronize access to the vector, too, if you share it between threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advisement. Especially for the vector<thread> part, because the final project would use a vector to store the client threads.

Comment: It turns out  the vector reallocation causes all the trouble. The clients reallocates and the client_threads reallocates.